# How to structure a component using React Hooks with an object that uses the DOM directly? (such as OpenLayers)?)

Tags: reactjs, openlayers, react-hooks

I'm trying out using React Hooks where in a component that I previously have as class based. The component looks like this:

```
class A extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.mapRef = createRef()
  this.map = new Map({ ... })
 }

 componentDidMount() {
  this.map.setTarget(this.mapRef.current)
 }

 // Also shouldComponentUpdate & componentWillUnmount

 render() {
  return (
   <div>
    <div ref={this.mapRef}></div>
    {this.props.children({map: this.map})}
   </div>
  )
 }
}
```

My understanding of the open-layers library is that when I create an instance of the Map object, I need to pass it a reference to a DOM element since the library requires direct control over a DOM element. I'm doing this in the `componentDidMount` function via a `ref`.

Trying to change this code to React Hooks (out of interest), I have tried this:

```
function A (props) {
 var map
 const mapRef = useRef(null)

 useEffect(() => {
  map = new Map()
  map.setTarget(mapRef.current)
 })

  return (
   <div>
    <div ref={mapRef}></div>
    {props.children({map})}
   </div>
  )
}
```

Which just errors (because the `props.children` function gets `null` for the map object). I tried moving the map object initialization out of the function, which seems to work:

```
const map = new Map({ ... })
function A (props) {
 const mapRef = useRef(null)

 useEffect(() => {
  map.setTarget(mapRef.current)
  // Then adjust the map however necessary depending on props
 })

  return (
   <div>
    <div ref={mapRef}></div>
    {props.children({map})}
   </div>
  )
}
```

This somewhat works... although it seems that the `useEffect` callback fires far more often then necessary. And I have to figure out how to implement `shouldComponentUpdate`.

Is this the 'correct' approach to using React Hooks? I can't help feeling that in this case either a class component makes a lot more sense, or I'm not using Hooks correctly (probably the latter).

In this case I'm not actually using a class component for state at all, but rather for the ability to use lifecycle methods to update the map instance due to DOM changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a useful question for me when I was trying to create my own Map component with OpenLayers. I used a slightly different approach:

The `olMap.setTarget` method accepts [either an HTML element or the ID of one](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_Map-Map.html#setTarget). So I construct the initial OlMap object and give the target key a value of `undefined`. The target is then set in a `useEffect` to the `div`'s id.

To make sure this effect only runs when the component mounts and not on each render, an empty array is passed as the second parameter to `useEffect`. The effect returns a function that sets the target back to `undefined` when the component unmounts. This part is necessary if the map is in a component that is only rendered on certain routes. The map will not re-render if you navigate away and then back if you don't set the target again.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Map, View } from 'ol';
const olMap = new Map({
  target: undefined,
  layers: [
    new TileLayer({
      source: new OSM()
    })
  ],
  view: new View({
    center: [-6005420.749222653, 6000508.181331601],
    zoom: 9
  })
});

export default function OlMap() {
  useEffect(() => {
    olMap.setTarget('map')
    return () => olMap.setTarget(undefined);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div id='map'>
    </div>
  )
}
```

If you are using a library that needs a `HTMLElement` you can use `useRef` and `ref` instead:

```
export default function OlMap() {
  let mapDiv = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    olMap.setTarget(mapDiv.current)
    return () => olMap.setTarget(undefined);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div id='map' ref={mapDiv}>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I've left the second parameter as an empty array again, but you could pass `mapDiv` in that array if you wanted to call the effect again should the `ref` ever change. I don't think this is needed for OpenLayers, but another library might make changes other than just appending to the target `HTMLElement`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the useEffect hook to fire only when needed you can put an array with the properties that would trigger the hook as a second argument.

```
useEffect(() => {map.setTarget(...)}, [mapRef.current])
```